# How patch class in TypeScript with a Polyfill

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

Hello I recently started working with TypeScript, I decided to migrate a WebComponent I started with the base of the component I am trying to import a polyfill (construct-style-sheets-polyfill) that extends the functionality of the CSSStyleSheet class but I can't make TypeScript recognize the "replaceSync" method that is added in the Polyfill

How can I make TypeScript update the class definition with the Polyfill methods?

```
import {patch, elementOpen, elementClose} from 'incremental-dom';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements'
import 'construct-style-sheets-polyfill';
import * as reset_style from './reset.scss';

const sheet:CSSStyleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
sheet.replaceSync(reset_style);
```

> Error:(7, 8) TS2339: Property 'replaceSync' does not exist on type
> 'CSSStyleSheet'.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "construct-style-sheets-polyfill": "^2.4.2",
    "incremental-dom": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "declarations.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is [merge your interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).

In your `declarations.d.ts` file, include the following

```
interface CSSStyleSheet {
  replaceSync(reset_style: any): void
}
```